# UI-grid splice last column & bootstrap dropdown in cell

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-ui-grid

I need to get the data from the ui-grid, so I did it this way:

```
$scope.getData = function() {
  var a = $scope.gridOpts.data;   

  alert(JSON.stringify(a));
}
```

But it shows some extra column and I wanted to splice it. Have you any idea?
http://plnkr.co/edit/na8FmrWVm7kHr4h7lRPh?p=preview

And second question... why the dropdowns don't show?

Answer (score 0):

```
 var b = $scope.gridOpts.columnDefs.splice(3,4);
```

to splice the last column

Comment: Did that but nothing changed:       $scope.gridOpts.columnDefs.splice(3,4);
alert(JSON.stringify($scope.gridOpts.data));

Comment: u want to splice it on load ?? or on click of the button get data from the table ??

Comment: second. get spliced data in alert

Comment: earlier one was wrong if u use

      var b = $scope.gridOpts.columnDefs.splice(3,1); u can splice the 4th column